# How to create a PowerBI New Column by extracting from an existing column?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

This is the existing column value: "DisplaySize:0,0.1"
New Column value should be : DisplaySize , if 0,0.1 is present in the existing value, other wise it should be whatever was previously set in the older column.

Answer (score 0):

NewColumn = IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("0,0.1",Column1[Value]),-1)=-1 ,Column1[Value],SUBSTITUTE(MID(Column1[Value], 1,SEARCH("0,0.1",Column1[Value])-2), """", ""))